# Scraping data from DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have been tasked with doing some data scraping from [Wall Street Journal](http://projects.wsj.com/medicarebilling).
After selecting a city, I was given a beautiful, sortable, paginated table; however, upon downloading the HTML source, I was unable to find any data.

Some detective work has revealed the data is being displayed by [DataTables](https://datatables.net), but I am unable to summon scriptable-data.

How might I gain script-access to data from DataTables?

Comment: This is where all of their main DataTables code is: http://projects.wsj.com/medicarebilling/js/script.min.js?v=d7116ab750 but I see they are using pagination, not infinite scroll. The question is to discover where the json is being fed from.

Comment: I couldn't find "sAjaxSource" in the output HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like submit button calls an AJAX request to retrieve the data which means the data is not included in the source of the page, you can track the network through browser utility.  by the way i found that the AJAX request is being made to [this](http://projects.wsj.com/medicarebilling/demo-api/search.php?name=&special=&city=&state=AK&_=) url having some parameters which define its search criteria, and after requesting to this url the returned response comes in JSON format which is seriously very easy to parse, and your are lucky that this service does not require authentication method, which means you can download all the available data.
[Example](http://projects.wsj.com/medicarebilling/demo-api/search.php?name=&special=Internal%20Medicine&city=&state=AK&_=1431548325442) url, have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try variations on the curl call below. If you're not sure where to start, the best thing to do is to open up your developer console in your favorite browser, and watch the network sections as you bring data in. From my looking, its clear they are using all sorts of data sources - for the maps, for the doctors list, for the content for each. It's quite a complicated little app they've got.

```
curl 'http://projects.wsj.com/medicarebilling/js/doc-cards.json' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://projects.wsj.com/medicarebilling/' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Cookie: __gads=ID=646810c03a66f80b:T=1427824722:S=ALNI_MbI1faJHjFHYyBE5Rc3RQEAACeljg; DJCOOKIE=ORC%3Dna%2Cus%7C%7CFCFGOOGLE%3D0%7C%7CFCFEXPGOOGLE%3D1431107109182; wsjregion=na%2Cus; utag_main=v_id:014c70fc41b60002799e4a2c78f90d078006007000fb8$_sn:3$_ss:1$_st:1431022512625$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1431020712625%3Bexp-session; s_fid=2A4A81015DE138F0-0436DAF9EC0F16F9; bkuuid=pjKMOz6q99OAYVkD; cX_P=i2xkpuyp35cvld6r; s_vnum=1432229868915%26vn%3D2; rsi_ct=2015_5_13:2; s_cc=true; s_invisit=true; gpv_pn=WSJ_infogrfx_interactive_MEDDATA1214_Medicare%20Unmasked%3A%20Behind%20the%20Numbers; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed
```